# PandasのSeriesがawareかnaiveかを判定する方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas

あるDataFrameの列(pd.Series)が日付型であるか、
また日付型であればawareなのか、naiveなのかを判定したいです。
以下のように、判定メソッドを作成したのですが、Seriesの先頭要素を取得して判定しています。
もっとスマートな方法ありましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか？
ゼロ件チェックした上に、先頭要素を参照しているところが気持ち悪く、気になっています。
（先頭要素を見ることなく、Seriesオブジェクトから、naiveかどうか判定できますでしょうか？）

```
import typing as t
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd


def is_aware(series: pd.Series) -> t.Optional[bool]:
    """タイムゾーンをもつデータ型かどうか判定する。

        日付型で、awareならTrue
        日付型で、naiveならFalse
        それ以外の型ならNone
        を返す。
    """
    if not series.empty:
        data = series.iloc[0]
        if isinstance(data, dt.datetime):  # pd.Timestampはdt.datetimeから継承されている
            return data.tzinfo is not None
    return None


df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        {
            'timestamp_aware': pd.Timestamp('2024/02/01', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
            'timestamp_naive': pd.Timestamp('2024/02/01'),
            'datetime_aware': dt.datetime(2021, 1, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=dt.timezone(dt.timedelta(hours=9))),
            'datetime_naive': dt.datetime(2024, 2, 1, 0, 0),
            'other': 'other_type1'
        },
        {
            'timestamp_aware': pd.Timestamp('2024/02/02', tz='Asia/Tokyo'),
            'timestamp_naive': pd.Timestamp('2024/02/02'),
            'datetime_aware': dt.datetime(2021, 1, 2, 0, 0, tzinfo=dt.timezone(dt.timedelta(hours=9))),
            'datetime_naive': dt.datetime(2024, 2, 2, 0, 0),
            'other': 'other_type2'
        },
    ],
    index=['aa', 'bb'])
display(df)


print('timestamp_aware:', is_aware(df['timestamp_aware']))
print('timestamp_naive:', is_aware(df['timestamp_naive']))
print('datetime_aware:', is_aware(df['datetime_aware']))
print('datetime_naive:', is_aware(df['datetime_naive']))
print('other:', is_aware(df['other']))
```

以下、実行結果です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype — pandas 2.2.0 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype.html) を利用するとよいかと思います。

```py
from pandas.api.types import is_datetime64_any_dtype
from operator import attrgetter

def is_aware(series: pd.Series) -> t.Optional[bool]:
    """タイムゾーンをもつデータ型かどうか判定する。

        日付型で、awareならTrue
        日付型で、naiveならFalse
        それ以外の型ならNone
        を返す。
    """

    if is_datetime64_any_dtype(series):
        return series.map(attrgetter('tzinfo')).notnull().all()
    return None
```

Comment: 理解できました。スマートな書き方ができるようになります。ありがとうございます。